# Format for start_date/timestamp in Swagger?

Tags: api, swagger

I am trying to test the 'asset-stats-history' call of [this API](https://api.bzx.network/#/), but I keep getting an error for the date/timestamp fields. I haven't able to find any ways to have it go through. I've tried the following formats unsuccessfully:

```
27-09-2020
2020-09-27
2020-09-27T19:23:52Z
1601235908752 (in ms, for example what I get for console.log(Date.now()))
2020-09-27 19:23:52
```

Any ideas what might work? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I asked the developers and it was Unix time (so in ms, for example [this website](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) can help you convert dates to unix time)